# Deploying Dot Net Project to AWS Lambda Using Jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins, deployment, aws-lambda, continuous-deployment

[Post build action]...[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKcWE.jpg)[this is how my configuration looks like. ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdYmA.png)I am implementing Continuous Deployment of .Net to Lambda function. The project is being built successfully. I have configured, AWS Lambda functions, Post-build Actions on Jenkins. But getting error 
"com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.AWSLambdaException: 1 validation error detected: Value '' at 'handler' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [^\s]+ (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: f02c9383-14da-11e9-a41e-47f2ba783fa5". What is the possible cause and how to solve that?

Comment: Can you share post-build action script. Also what tool are you using serverless-framework or SAM or CF?

Comment: @AtharKhan i have pasted image of my configuration

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by providing the relative path of the zipped artifacts. I was providing the absolute path.